# Glue table behaving differently for EMR than Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-emr, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a table set up on glue, meta store. It points to a bunch of constantly updating parquet files on s3, inside a bucket with todays date on it. There is a new folder for each day.

If I am to query todays date, through Athena on AWS, it todays partition it shows all the records. Thousands of them.
If I am do do a similar query on EMR, using the spark.table("tableName") in Scala I get significantly less records.

Two very different behaviours.

There is a process in place that does lots of things to the data on EMR. I must get this solution working in EMR.

Where do I begin to troubleshoot and fix this in EMR spark using scala? Is there a code or something which tells the Glue table, to go and update itself? Get an updated read from the underlying s3 bucket?

I am not sure why athena is seeing it differently from EMR.

Comment: Could you provide your query and your EMR code?

Comment: Do you have `consistency view` enabled on the cluster? If yes then try running `emrfs sync s3://<bucket-name>/`, then run the query again see if anything changes. Its not a solution, Im just trying to figure it out what could be the issue.

Comment: Sorry, let me add further information to this post. I think I know what it is not doing correctly, but am not sure how to solve it. There is a folder of parquet files, and inside that folder is a subfolder with parquet. Athena is able to read into all folders and subs, it seems EMR and Spark isn't doing it. How do I fix it? Is it recursive reads or something?